# Are there overnight bus from Chiang Mai to Chiang Khong?

Tags: buses, borders, thailand, laos, night-transport

I would like to cross the border between Thailand and Laos at Chiang Khong - Huay Xai, and I saw there are buses - direct or not - between Chiang Mai and Chiang Khong.

To save some time, I'd like to ideally get a direct overnight bus between Chiang Mai and Chiang Khong.

The Lonely Planet and wikivoyage mention some direct buses, twice daily but there are no details about whether they are overnight or not (I am afraid not since the duration is about 6 hours).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no night buses that I am aware of.

Green Bus has Chiang Mai to Chiang Khong routes (stops in Chiang Rai on the way), but they are daytime schedules.  Most bus companies try to avoid driving the road between Chiang Mai and Chiang Rai at night, as it is a winding mountain route with less than perfect drivers (ie post drinking drivers).

Comment: I am confirming the road is winding (and the driving is scary). I forgot to ask for the bus times in Chiang Mai though.

Comment: I am not sure of the current schedule, but last time I looked it was a morning and an early afternoon departure.  Green Bus does have a website with schedules posted.